# What could go wrong if I use public IP range for intranet?

Tags: lan

One of out clients is using a sub-network of 172.168.100.0/24 or

Comment: The users on that network could never contact or use any services of the real owner of that network on the public Internet. If the owners of that network assign it to users, those users would find it difficult to impossible to do business with the company using it for an intranet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They'll accidentally allow public IP traffic through ACLs and reduce the effectiveness of their perimeter security design.

They'll also make parts of the real Internet inaccessible to themselves.  The specific subnet you mention, `172.168.100.0/24`, is used by Oath.  IIRC that's a division of Verizon that has to do with advertising.

You should definitely help them fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not reaching those addresses is not even the worst part. Lot of security software can go haywire when they see typical LAN behavior coming from an “external” address. Symantec, for example, was blocking a client’s DHCP and AD traffic because it was coming from a 192.170.x.x address.
Also VPN connections might break and NAT tables go crazy. Once I connected with a VPN into that site and our port forwarding broke and people started losing connectivity on the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad practice and not recommended to uses public ip address pools for configuring in LAN segments . As Lan grows scalablity will be a problem. We cannot isolate networks ,